# "Random" facts that math can prove (eg, there are at least 2 people on the planet with the exact same number of body hairs)

Tags: soft-question, examples-counterexamples, big-list

I just learned that you can prove mathematically that in the entire planet, there are at least 2 people with the exact same amount of body hairs.

I was fascinated by this and I searched for more seemingly "random" facts that mathematics can prove, and I found that you can prove that there are always 2 places on the planet with no wind blowing.

I continued searching but I couldn't find any more of this facts that math can prove.

Does anyone know any "random" or cool facts that mathematics can prove?

Comment: speaking of hair, [you can't comb a hairy ball flat without creating a cowlick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem)

Comment: I have to say the number of hairs result has a different flavor to me than the places where the wind is blowing result. It is clear that it’s supposed to be a pigeonhole problem. But for the latter result (wind), you just need to know the earth is a topological sphere. For the former result (hair), you need to know the biophysical limit of the number of hairs on a human body is less than, say, 8 billion. This is a little less obvious: most audiences will know the earth is a sphere but won’t know this biophysical limit on the number of hairs a body can have — without googling.

Comment: Until you (at least attempt to) give criteria for what constitutes a "random" as opposed to a non-"random" fact, I find this question unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an accurate map of a place, no matter how much you scrunch it up while in that place, there will always be a point on that map directly above the point it represents.

Comment: What's the math underlying this? It seems like some kind of fixed-point theorem.

Comment: I believe it is an application of the [contraction mapping theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), @Semiclassical.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHjQhliXUB0

Comment: At least, as long as you're standing within that place. Obviously if you're standing outside the region the map refers to, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the 4-colour theorem, which states that any map with contiguous countries can be coloured with 4 colours or fewer so that no 2 countries that share a border have the same colour (although two countries with the same colour can meet at a corner).